# In EF, is it efficient to delete a parent row by deleting the child rows referencing it first through the child row clones?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity

```
        public void Delete(Dinner dinner)
        {
            List<RSVP> rsvps = dinner.RSVPs.ToList();// This clone looks inefficient.

            foreach (RSVP rsvp in rsvps)
                entities.RSVPs.DeleteObject(rsvp);

            entities.Dinners.DeleteObject(dinner);
        }
```

[image]

**QUESTION:**

Deleting a parent row by deleting the child rows referencing it first through the child row clones looks inefficient.

Duplicating the child rows will consume huge resources I think.

If so, what is the better way?

**EDIT 1:**

```
namespace NerdDinner.Models
{
    public class DinnerRepository
    {
        private NerdDinnerEntities entities = new NerdDinnerEntities();

        public IQueryable<Dinner> FindAllDinners()
        {
            return entities.Dinners;
        }

        public IQueryable<Dinner> FindUpcomingDinners()
        {
            return from dinner in entities.Dinners
                   where dinner.EventDate > DateTime.Now
                   orderby dinner.EventDate
                   select dinner;
        }

        public Dinner GetDinnerByID(int DinnerID)
        {
            return entities.Dinners.FirstOrDefault(d => d.DinnerID == DinnerID);
        }

        public void Add(Dinner dinner)
        {
            entities.Dinners.AddObject(dinner);
        }

        public void Delete(Dinner dinner)
        {
            //List<RSVP> rsvps = dinner.RSVPs.ToList();

            //foreach (RSVP rsvp in dinner.RSVPs)
            //    entities.RSVPs.DeleteObject(rsvp);

            entities.Dinners.DeleteObject(dinner);
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            entities.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just do this on the DB level, set the delete rule to cascade on the foreign key.

Comment: OK. Thanks. So I just need to delete dinner object.

Comment: Yes. the database will delete the child objects for you. Doggett you should have given this as an answer :) now I can't give it ... since you came up with it first ... and neither of us get the reputation :)

Comment: @Ali, Cascading has a side effect on transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the delete rule to cascade on the foreign key, then when you delete the dinner object the database will automatically remove all child records.

Keep in mind, this probably won't be reflected down to EF so any objects already in memory will not be marked as deleted.

Comment: So what should I do to avoid that issue?

Comment: With your current 2 tables it shouldn't be a problem, assuming the RSVP's aren't accessed outside of the dinners anyhow

Comment: Please see my EDIT 1. If I use the repository pattern as shown above, and instantiate the repository class locally inside a method, the issue you said above still happens? Or should I move the datacontext object to local declaration instead of class level declaration?

Comment: Hi Doggett, I got the detail from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738695.aspx. I must implement cascade rule on both EF and the physical database.